# Thingworx client for windows 10

Tags: windows, api, thingworx

I want to gather some information from a windows 10 machine over the internet using the thingworx platform. 
Here's a scenario:

1. Admin logs into thingworx app
2. Exisiting or new computer (windows 10 ) is added (serial number computer)
3. Thingworx platform creates a thing based on a created template
4. User receives application key which will be entered on a client which is installed on the computer
5. Client is started based on event and sends data to thingworx platform
6. Communication is secured

Is there a best practice or even a client available / open source or Licence based which relieves the headache of security etc.?

Comment: Reading myself into the topic, thingworx comes with a "alwaysOn" websocket protocol. Three different types have to mentioned, binary executable, software development kit and a stand alone version. The binary executable relates to a microServer and can receive information using the lula script framework. The Software Development SDK comes in a JAVA SDK and a C SDK. Depending on the IoT device (Android, iOS or .NET) you can choose which suit you the best. Last not least there is a REST API. This REST API is used in the tutorial, provided by PTC...POSTMAN is used for testing.

Comment: Will post my progress...

Comment: wrote rest api in java using okhttp3.OkHttpClient.. Found a class to read PowerShell calls ….com.profesorfalken.jpowershell….and finally used com.google.gson.Gson; to assemble the content for the rest call.

Comment: Works perfectly..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, alwaysOn is used mostly as web socket protocol for communication between devices & ThingWorx platform. Apart from these one case also use MQTT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for Demo/Academic Purpose then use Thingworx Academic Simulator. I have been using it for Testing many scenarios.

Download Link - http://apps.ptc.com/schools/software/ThingWorxAcademicSimulatorSetup.exe